# Why do not we have checksum validation in the application Level (BGP , RIP)?

Tags: bgp, tcp, protocol-theory, rip, checksum

In BGP, TCP handles the checksum and BGP does not perform any checksum validation in the application level.

How can we believe TCP must forward the data without errors?

Similarly in RIP with UDP case?

Comment: Dear user2720323, could you please use the preview to check if your questions are readable before posting? Every single question you've asked had to be edited because it was unreadable due to improper use of markup. Thank you!

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Allow me to quote Mr. Jeff Doyle

> Like EGP, BGP forms a unique, unicast-based connection to each of its BGP-speaking peers. To increase the reliability of the peer connection, BGP uses TCP (port 179) as its underlying delivery mechanism.  The update mechanisms of BGP are also somewhat simplified by allowing the TCP layer to handle such duties as acknowledgment, retransmission and sequencing.  Because BGP rides on TCP, a separate point to-point connection to each peer must be established.” Jeff Doyle - *Routing TCP/IP, Volume II*

On the other hand, another routing protocol OSPF rides on IP (protocol #89). OSPF performs its own delivery mechanism utilizing features like LSAcks and a checksum in the packet header.